# Parameter in Ionic2 custom component not displayed

Tags: components, ionic2

I am trying to build a simple component, just a div that prints a parameter but the parameter isn't been displayed:

test.html

```
<ion-content padding class="getting-started">
   <my-component [test]="Something"></my-component>
</ion-content>
```

test.ts

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import {MyComponent} from './myComponent';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/test/test.html',
    directives: [MyComponent]
})

export class TestPage {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

myComponent.ts

```
import {Component,Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div>Param: {{test}}</div>
   `,
})

export class MyComponent {
  @Input() test;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

The result:

[image: No text displayed]

I can't figure it out what I am missing.

Comment: .. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is the same as the documentation (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html) except for the `[test]="Something"`, have your tried to write `test="Something"` instead ?

I think `[]` syntax can take only variable of component.

Comment: As easy as that ... Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but try [test]="'Something'"